# Sending an Image as a Byte Array to a REST Service

Tags: c#, image, rest, image-processing, byte

I am working on a REST service which will be used to manipulate an image for example, change brightness or contrast. I currently have a Windows Form App to which I upload an image to before I send it to the Rest.

Here is the code I have so far on the Rest to receive the byte:

**IRestServiceImpl.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
string jsonData(byte[] id);
```

**RestServiceImpl.svc.cs**

```
public string jsonData(byte[] id) {
    return "The byte array is" + id;
}
```

This is my attempt to send it from the form but it just returns blank in Visual Studio's console.

```
private async void btnRestSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        byte[] byteArray = ImageManipulation.ImgToByte(pictureBox1.Image);
        ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
        var url = "http://localhost:52278/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), byteContent);

        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
```

**ImgToByte**

```
public static byte[] ImgToByte(Image img) {
    //Converts an Image to a Byte
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

How do I get the byte array to be successfully sent to the rest service so I can manipulate it in there?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the byte array to a base 64 string in order to send it to front-end as a string or inside a JSON object.

```
string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

*Convert belongs to System library